# Problems passing info via prepareForSegue, I cant figure it out

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have already asked this question but perhaps not clear enough as I did not get any responses... Anyway here is my second attempt to get an answer.

I have a simple app that has 2 views, each view has it's class set in the storyboard to a specific classname.

1. Main View (MainViewController)
2. ClientDetailView (ClientDetailViewController)

In the main view I have a list that displays a list of my "Clients" which for now is just a list of email addresses. When you click on the email I want to transition to the second view with the email of the row in the list that was clicked.

On the ClientDetail view I have a property setup to accept the email address called key. Assuming there were no error I assign key to the Text to a UILabel so I can see that the right data was passed.

OK Time for some code.

Here is my prepareForSegue Method, you can see some comments because I have been trying different things...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showClientDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ClientDetailViewController *destViewController = (ClientDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //destViewController.key = [self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [destViewController setKey:[self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Here is the output that I get when the exception is thrown

```
2013-05-21 13:56:50.484 ClientManager[19728:11603] -[NSManagedObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8624f90
2013-05-21 13:56:50.485 ClientManager[19728:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8624f90'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1fa4012 0x13e1e7e 0x202f4bd 0x1f93bbc 0x1f9394e 0x1764af 0x176674 0x5871 0xfe817 0xfe882 0xfeb2a 0x115ef5 0x115fdb 0x116286 0x116381 0x116eab 0x1174a3 0x117098 0x472da3 0x464ad9 0x464b54 0xcc899 0xccb3d 0xad3e83 0x1f63376 0x1f62e06 0x1f4aa82 0x1f49f44 0x1f49e1b 0x1efe7e3 0x1efe668 0x1d65c 0x1e2d 0x1d55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I have read & re read tutorials, stack trace and I cannot figure this out. I am pretty new to iOS dev and would really appreciate some help from the experts out there.

If I haven't posted enough info Please do not down vote my post or insult me, like I said I am new to this so let me know what I could add that could help with a solution.

Thanks

-------------Update---------------

OK So after some advice I ran this in the debugger

```
p (char*)object_getClassName(self.clients[0])
```

And it looks like part of the problem is that when I call setKey I am referenceing an object NSManagedObjec_Client, so now it make sense why it is failing.

From here I am not sure how to get the property of the object to set the key with.

Here is what I have in MainViewController.m

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *clients;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Client"];
    self.clients = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

So based on that I assume I need to somehow cast the NSManagedObject_Client_ and get the emailAddress property. Does that sound right? How do I do it?

Comment: Instead of asking the question a second time, you should edit your original question with the updated information by clicking `edit` beneath the tags at the bottom of your question.  Duplicate questions are strongly discouraged here as they create redundant information which would be better kept in one place.  Please delete one of your questions, or else they will most likely get closed as a duplicate by the community!  :)

Comment: As far as your problem, determine which line is causing the error.  I'm guessing that it is in the method setKey or something else in your  `ClientDetailView` class, and nothing with your segue here.

Comment: How do you declare key in ClientDetailController? If you've overridden the setter for that property, you should show the code for that too.

Comment: @synthesize key = _key;-(void)setKey:(NSString *)key
{
    _key = key;
}

Comment: What is it that you want key to be? One of the attributes of your managed object? Or, do you want the managed object itself?

Comment: I would like to set key to a property of the managed object. So In in my datamodel I have a Client Entity with an EmailAddress attribute. I would like to pass that EmailAddress to the Detail View. From the tutorials that I have been through setting up a property (key) on the destination and using a setter seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `clients` array doesn't really contains `NSString`s, but `NSManageObject`s. You can verify by adding a breakpoint right before `[destViewController setKey:...]` and running `p (char*)object_getClassName(self.clients[0])` in the debugger.

Comment: You are correct when I run that command I get   (char *) $2 = 0x112576c0 "NSManagedObject_Client_" not sure where to go from here though

Comment: OK I figured it out thanks to you... I needed to get the keyValue for the object not the object itself.            NSManagedObject *client = [self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *email = [client valueForKey:@"emailAddress"];
        [destViewController setKey:email];

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
[destViewController setKey:[self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

passes the managed object itself. If you want to pass the emailAddress attribute, then you have to use valueForKey on the managed object:

```
[destViewController setKey:[[self.clients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"emailAddress"];
```

I think "key" might be a somewhat confusing name for your property. It has nothing to do with the key you need to pass to valueForKey:. I think it would be better to call it emailAddress or something similarly descriptive of what it represents.

Comment: You are correct, I figured it out before your post but thanks that was exactly my problem.